# Riddle -- What am I? Q1

Tags: riddle, rhyme

You can see me almost everywhere, at almost every place.

You can turn me around and push me, but you'll never see my face.

You can hold me tight and release me, but you'll never see me fall.

You can lock me up or set me free, but I never leave at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answer:

> Doorknob

Explanation:
You can see me almost everywhere, at almost every place.

> Most doors have them, and doors are everywhere.

You can turn me around and push me, but you'll never see my face.

> Door knobs are turned and pushed.  Not sure about the face though.

You can hold me tight and release me, but you'll never see me fall.

> You grip the doorknob to turn it, then release it.

You can lock me up or set me free, but I never leave at all.

> Doors are locked or unlocked, but the doorknob stays there.

Comment: That's it. Congrats!

Comment: Cool.  I'm not so sure about the "never see my face" part though.

Comment: Never seen one fall?! :p

Answer (score 2):

**Partial Answer:**

> memory

You can see me almost everywhere, at almost every place

> You can have flashbacks anytime, anywhere

You can turn me around and push me, but you'll never see my face

> Still working on this one

... hold me tight and release me ...

> You can hold memory for use in a program, and release it when you're done

You can lock me up and set me free, but I never leave at all

> You can get in a deadlock with memory, and you free memory when you're done with it. However, the same amount of memory is still on the computer

Comment: Sorry. Good guess though -- it almost works.

Comment: you can look into a memory from every angle ("turn me around") to understand a situation, or because you love this memory. and you can repulse ("push me") because it's painful. You won't be able to see it's face: it's a memory so the instant is gone forever